# Who exactly is "him" Herman referring to?

Tags: dialogue, mank

A scene from *Mank (2020)*, starts with a thick script hitting the table. A camera tilts up to show
Charlie Lederer standing and holding a hat. Then a wider angle shot reveals Herman is
sitting in a chair. Charlie Lederer is standing opposite to him and Rita, with binoculars,
is birdwatching:

> Charlie Lederer: What can I say? She's my aunt
>
> Herman: Oh, it's not about her, it's about **him**. Or rather, it's **him**,
> but it's not her.
>
> Charlie Lederer: The lonely showgirl, trapped in a castle, doing
> jigsaw puzzles.

Who exactly is "him" Herman referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

William Randolph Hearst.
That's the whole point of the final confrontation between him and Mank.